# Do Sagemaker ML instance types use Nitro system based on instance type pattern?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker

Only certain EC2 instance types are build on the [Nitro System](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html#ec2-nitro-instances)

Sagemaker [instance types](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/instance-types/) follow the pattern of `ml.{ec2 instance type}`

If the `{ec2 instance type}` for an Amazon Sagemaker training instance was built on the [Nitro System](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html#ec2-nitro-instances), can I deduce that the model training instance was *also* built on the Nitro system?

For example, M5 EC2 instances were built on the Nitro System. Does this mean that a Sagemaker ml.m5.xlarge instance is *also* built on the Nitro System?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that assumption is correct.